# Morris.js donut chart not displaying chart when getting data through Ajax from php script

Tags: jquery, ajax, morris.js, donut-chart

I am working on displaying data through a morris.js donut chart. These data come from a MySQL database through PHP and ajax.

The typical example where you type the data to be displayed right in the code is working fine

```
Morris.Donut({
            element: 'donut-example',
            data: [
              { label: "Download Sales", value: 12 },
              { label: "In-Store Sales", value: 30 },
              { label: "Mail-Order Sales", value: 20 }]
        });
```

however, when i call the data from the database, the chart is not displayed. Moreover, firebug does not show any errors.

This is the output i get from PHP:

```
[{label: "4 pairs",value: "9"},{label: "3 pairs",value: "9"},{label: "2 pairs",value: "6"},{label: "5 pairs",value: "3"},{label: "6 pairs",value: "2"},{label: "1 pair",value: "2"}]
```

Actually, I tried this output by copying inside the Morris.Donut(); function and it worked fine!

And this is the Ajax code (which doesn't work at all):

```
$.ajax({
    url: "ajax/modas_pares.php",
    type: "post",
    data: {lotto: 'the_lotto', limit: 20},
    success : function (resp){
        //alert(resp);
        Morris.Donut({
            element: 'donut-example',
            data: resp
        });
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, ex) {
      console.log(textStatus + "," + ex + "," + jqXHR.responseText);
    }
});
```

However, if i have the following code:

```
$.ajax({
            url: "ajax/modas_pares.php",
            cache: false,
            type: "post",
            data: {lotto: 'the_lotto', limit: 20},
            //dataType: "json",
            timeout:3000,
            success : function (resp){
                //var column_data = $.parseJSON(resp);
                //alert(resp);
                Morris.Donut({
                    element: 'donut-example',
                    data: [{label: "3 pairs",value: "6"},{label: "4 pairs",value: "5"},{label: "2 pairs",value: "5"},{label: "5 pairs",value: "3"},{label: "1 pair",value: "1"},{label: "6 pairs",value: "1"}]
                });
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, ex) {
              console.log(textStatus + "," + ex + "," + jqXHR.responseText);
            }
        });
```

It does work, fine!!!

What i don't get is that, if i tried passing the code through a variable, it does not work!! :

```
$string='[{label: "4 pairs",value: "9"},{label: "3 pairs",value: "9"},{label: "2 pairs",value: "6"},{label: "5 pairs",value: "3"},{label: "6 pairs",value: "2"},{label: "1 pair",value: "2"}]';
?>
```

And

```
$.ajax({
            url: "ajax/modas_pares.php",
            cache: false,
            type: "post",
            data: {lotto: 'the_lotto', limit: 20},
            //dataType: "json",
            timeout:3000,
            success : function (resp){
                //var column_data = $.parseJSON(resp);
                //alert(resp);
                Morris.Donut({
                    element: 'donut-example',
                    data: '<?php echo $string ?>'
                });
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, ex) {
              console.log(textStatus + "," + ex + "," + jqXHR.responseText);
            }
        });
```

It doesn't work :( if i get it either from a php variable or from a php script through ajax :/

What am i missing? How can i fix this? Why?????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error comes right where you set up the array. In the PHP section you should make the array as follows:

```
$resp = array(
      array('label' => '5 pairs','value' => 4),
      array('label' => '3 pairs','value' => 8)
);
echo json_encode( $resp );
```

Then you can use:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "ajax/modas_pares.php",
        type: "post",
        data: {loteria: 'melate', limit: 20},
        dataType: "json",
        timeout:3000,
        success : function (resp){
            Morris.Donut({
                element: 'donut-example',
                data: resp
            });
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, ex) {
          console.log(textStatus + "," + ex + "," + jqXHR.responseText);
        }
    });
```

Comment: @BitNinja Done!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Typical example worked fine but not when you bring data in dynamically. I solved it as follow:

```
setTimeout(function () {
        Morris.Donut({
            element: 'donut-example',
            data: newArray
        },2000);

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

whenever you get an error like this(especially on morris donut chart), just insert your result from controller into a variable first, then use the variable into `data:`
e.g :

i assumse you had convert your query result into json using `json_encode()` function

```
var data = res;
// or
var data = "<?php echo $variable_from_controller_or_your_query_result ?>";
Morris.Donut({
       element : 'your div id',
       data : data,
});
```

the example above will work if

> your data has converted into json

hope my example help someone who need the answer to solve their problem :D

Answer (score 0):

I had to load data dynamically into morris chart. After readings through the issue and solutions provided, this worked for me.

Javascript

```
     $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "./assets/content/analytics/dashboard/customer_cat_donut.php",
        data: dataString,
        dataType: "json",
        beforeSend: function () {

        },
        success: function (data) {

            Morris.Donut({
                element: 'div_cus_category_graph_view',
                data: data,
                formatter: function (x) {
                    return x + "%"
                }
            }).on('click', function (i, row) {
                console.log(i, row);
            });

        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }


    });
```

PHP script

```
enter $sql = "SELECT customer.service_cat AS cat, COUNT(*) AS catnums FROM customer WHERE customer.ps_id='092301' GROUP by customer.service_cat;";
$r = mysqli_query($db, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($db));
$data = array();while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)) {
$row_data = array(
    'value' => intval($row['catnums']),
    'label' => strval($row['cat'])
);
array_push($data, $row_data);
}
echo json_encode($data);
```

I hope this solution makes things clearer.